# Why $(A -\lambda I)v$ is an eigenvector if $v$ is not?

Tags: linear-algebra

We have that the eigenvalue is only one real value, and we have a matrix of $2\times
2$, but I fail to see why $(A -\lambda I)v$ , I tried plugging the equation and using that the matrix satisfies its characteristic equation, but that didn't work, and I actually proof that that if we have real values with same magnitude and different sign, then $(A-\lambda ^2)v$ is an eigenvector if v is not.
Could it be this is false?, i read that in a book about structures.

Comment: Eigenvector...of what map/matrix? Not of $\;A\;$, right...?

Comment: Yes it from A, becouse if we have two eigenvalues $a, -a$ then $A(A- \lambda I)v) = A2v - \lambda 2 v$

Comment: Please put some order in your sentences. Not really intelligible.

Comment: Well, did you omit putting some really important info in your question or what...Not to mention the question is very poorly worded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you're saying that $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with only one eigenvalue, $\lambda$. If so then the characteristic polynomial is $$\det(A-tI)=(t-\lambda)^2,$$ so that $(A-\lambda I)^2=0$. So $$(A-\lambda I)(A-\lambda  I)v=0,$$so $(A-\lambda I)v$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: Of course, @David . I missed that. Thanks, deleting first comment.

Comment: I added a note about this leading to the Jordan form of $A.$ This is how I like to find it, find the minimal polynomial of degree $m$ for that eigenvalue and vector(s) such that $(A- \lambda I)^m v = 0$ but $(A- \lambda I)^{m-1} v \neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

The construction you describe is how to create the Jordan Normal Form for this matrix $A.$ You have a column vector $v$ with $(A - \lambda I) v \neq 0.$ Well, make a new column vector $u =(A - \lambda I) v.$ Then the matrix for $A$ in the ordered basis $u,v$ is 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 1 \\
0 & \lambda
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which is how Jordan is taught in the U.S. Last week, a guy from Uruguay said they put the extra $1$ below the main diagonal.

Anyway, if $R$ is the 2 by 2 matrix with left column $u$ and right column $v,$ then $R^{-1} AR = J$ is the Jordan form I showed above.